# Select some specific columns in a 4D Numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tensorflow, slice

I'm trying to select a specific number of columns in a 4D array but apparently the way to do this is different compare to 3D arrays, example:

```
numpy_vector = np.arange(0,120,dtype=np.int8)
numpy_tensor = numpy_vector.reshape(3,4,3,5)
```

The resulting tensor is this:

```
array([[[[   0,    1,    2,    3,    4],
         [   5,    6,    7,    8,    9],
         [  10,   11,   12,   13,   14]],

        [[  15,   16,   17,   18,   19],
         [  20,   21,   22,   23,   24],
         [  25,   26,   27,   28,   29]],

        [[  30,   31,   32,   33,   34],
         [  35,   36,   37,   38,   39],
         [  40,   41,   42,   43,   44]],

        [[  45,   46,   47,   48,   49],
         [  50,   51,   52,   53,   54],
         [  55,   56,   57,   58,   59]]],


       [[[  60,   61,   62,   63,   64],
         [  65,   66,   67,   68,   69],
         [  70,   71,   72,   73,   74]],

        [[  75,   76,   77,   78,   79],
         [  80,   81,   82,   83,   84],
         [  85,   86,   87,   88,   89]],

        [[  90,   91,   92,   93,   94],
         [  95,   96,   97,   98,   99],
         [ 100,  101,  102,  103,  104]],

        [[ 105,  106,  107,  108,  109],
         [ 110,  111,  112,  113,  114],
         [ 115,  116,  117,  118,  119]]],


       [[[ 120,  121,  122,  123,  124],
         [ 125,  126,  127, -128, -127],
         [-126, -125, -124, -123, -122]],

        [[-121, -120, -119, -118, -117],
         [-116, -115, -114, -113, -112],
         [-111, -110, -109, -108, -107]],

        [[-106, -105, -104, -103, -102],
         [-101, -100,  -99,  -98,  -97],
         [ -96,  -95,  -94,  -93,  -92]],

        [[ -91,  -90,  -89,  -88,  -87],
         [ -86,  -85,  -84,  -83,  -82],
         [ -81,  -80,  -79,  -78,  -77]]]], dtype=int8)
```

It has a shape of (3,4,3,5)

Now let's suppose that:

- I want the first and third array of the **first dimension**
- Then I want the third and fourth array of the **second dimension**
- Then I want the first and third row of the **third dimension**
- Finally I want the second, fourth and fifth column of the **fourth dimension** (the last one).

I tried to do it in the same way as with 3d arrays but either it gave me an error or the output was wrong, example:

```
- numpy_tensor[[0,2], [2,3], [0,2], [1,3,4]]
- output:
IndexError: shape mismatch: indexing arrays could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,) (2,) (2,) (3,) 

- numpy_tensor[[0,2],[[2,3]]]
- output:
array([[[[ 30,  31,  32,  33,  34],
         [ 35,  36,  37,  38,  39],
         [ 40,  41,  42,  43,  44]],

        [[-91, -90, -89, -88, -87],
         [-86, -85, -84, -83, -82],
         [-81, -80, -79, -78, -77]]]], dtype=int8)
```

I managed to get the result I wanted in the following way:

```
numpy_tensor[[0,2]][:, [2,3]][:,:,[0,2]][:,:,:,[1,3,4]]
```

Outpout:

```
array([[[[  31,   33,   34],
         [  41,   43,   44]],

        [[  46,   48,   49],
         [  56,   58,   59]]],


       [[[-105, -103, -102],
         [ -95,  -93,  -92]],

        [[ -90,  -88,  -87],
         [ -80,  -78,  -77]]]], dtype=int8)
```

But it seems very cumbersome, I don't know if there is a cleaner way to do it.

I've been working with numpy arrays for a while but this is the first time I've come across a 4-dimensional array. When it comes to slicing I have no problem but when I want to select a specific column is when I get confused.

Comment: tge `cumbersom` way is the right one.  Reread about `advanced indexing` and `broadcasting`., `np.ix_` is a useful utility .Conceptually 4d is no different from 3d or even 2d.

Answer (score 0):

```
numpy_tensor[(0,2), (2,3), (0,2), (1,3,4)]
```

This will return the same output as your previous method. The first tuple (0,2) specifies the indices for the first dimension, the second tuple (2,3) specifies the indices for the second dimension, and so on.
Using tuple indexing can be more concise and easier to read especially when you're dealing with more dimensions or more complex slices.